# Turn off transparency for Windows 7 taskbar only

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, transparency

I don't like the semi-transparent nature of the Windows 7 taskbar.  When a white window slides down there it makes the icons and, more importantly, the Workrave (http://www.workrave.org/) toolbar, hard to see.

Is there a way to disable transparency ONLY for the taskbar (I like it everywhere else).

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately as far as I know, it is only possible to do it for everything through `Control Panel` > `Personalization` > `Window Color`

I would be interested to see if anyone has a solution/reg hack or similar for just the taskbar though as I have the same problem as you sometimes when I drag a window under it (Explorer Windows).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a black wallpaper, or blacken the lower portion of your wallpaper using Paint. Alternatively, you can install the [ZoneTick Clock](http://zonetick.com/), which disables taskbar transparency while it is running.

Comment: +1 for suggesting blackening the bottom of the desktop image

Comment: It's not the wallpaper that's the problem for me, it's when I drag a window with a white background partially below the taskbar.  This seems to be something I do with great frequency, for some reason.  Since windows are on top of the wallpaper, changing the wallpaper wouldn't help.   ZoneTick clock is an interesting suggestion, though naturally I prefer a solution that's free.

Comment: As a last resort, you could try writing a quick program that uses the Desktop Window Manager API to do that. Here is a similar discussion: http://www.anuko.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=761